# How to pass textbox value directly through Query String in php

Tags: javascript, php

I want to pass textbox value directly through query string the first variable is passed but the second value will be textbox value on the same page. Please help. Thanks

```
<input type="text" name="txtswap" id="txtswap" size="5" />  

<a href="UserForm.php?operation=swap&id=<?php echo $row['id']; ?>">Swap</a>
```

Comment: I didn't understand what you want. the second value is id and it's value is generated by php. Where the input value should be placed ?

Comment: your question is not clear

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can't be done with PHP alone, you need some JavaScript for it:

```
<input type="text" name="txtswap" id="txtswap" size="5" />  
<a href="UserForm.php?operation=swap&id=<?php echo $row['id']; ?>" onclick="doSwap.call(this, event)">Swap</a>
```

JavaScript:

```
function doSwap(self, event)
{
    var swapValue = document.getElementById('txtswap').value;

    event.preventDefault();
    location.href = self.href + '&value=' + encodeURIComponent(swapValue);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<input type="text" name="txtswap" id="txtswap" size="5" />  

<a onclick="swap()" >Swap</a> 

<script> 
function swap() {  
var swapvalue  = $('#txtswap').val();

window.location.href = 'UserForm.php?operation=swap&id='+swapvalue ;
} 
</script>
```

Try this 
Not tested...

Answer (score 1):

Try this .

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="redirect()">Swap</a>
```

Write JavaScript function

```
    function redirect(){

     txtswap = document.getElementById("txtswap").value;
     window.location.href = "UserForm.php?operation=swap&id="+txtswap;

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the text box in the same page, you can't use PHP for this. PHP won't see the data (because it won't exist at the time the PHP runs).

Stop using a link and use a form instead, converting user input into a URLs is what they are for.

```
<form action="UserForm.php">
    <input type="hidden" name="operation" value="swap">
    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($row['id']; ?>">
    <input name="txtswap" id="txtswap" size="5">  
    <input type="submit" value="Swap">
</form>
```